# UserControl's PropertyChangedCallback doesn't run

Tags: c#, xaml

I have got an usercontrol with some dependency property. One of them (ValueProperty) has got a PropertyChangedCallback but it never run.

```
namespace test
{
public partial class IndicatorLigth : UserControl
    {
        public IndicatorLigth()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            CurrentBrush = new SolidColorBrush(InactiveColor);
            lIndicator.Background = CurrentBrush;
            TurnOnValue = true;
            Value = true;
        }       

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ActiveColor", typeof(Color), typeof(IndicatorLigth), new UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.Green));

        public Color ActiveColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(ActiveColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ActiveColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InactiveColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InactiveColor", typeof(Color), typeof(IndicatorLigth), new UIPropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));

        public Color InactiveColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(InactiveColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InactiveColorProperty, value); }
        }

        private SolidColorBrush _currentBrush;

        public SolidColorBrush CurrentBrush
        {
            get { return _currentBrush; }
            set { _currentBrush = value; }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TurnOnValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TurnOnValue", typeof(bool), typeof(IndicatorLigth), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));

        public bool TurnOnValue
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(TurnOnValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TurnOnValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(bool), typeof(IndicatorLigth),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true,
                                            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnSetColorChanged));

        public bool Value
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ValueProperty, value);                
            }
        }

        private void CheckStatus(bool sign)
        {            
            if (sign == TurnOnValue)
                CurrentBrush = new SolidColorBrush(ActiveColor);
            else CurrentBrush = new SolidColorBrush(InactiveColor);  
        }

        private static void OnSetColorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            IndicatorLigth mycontrol = d as IndicatorLigth;
            mycontrol.callmyInstanceMethod(e);
        }
        private void callmyInstanceMethod(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckStatus((bool)e.NewValue);
            lIndicator.Background = CurrentBrush;
        }
    }
}
```

And XAML where I use my usercontrol (I use it in another UserControl):

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" >
...
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
   <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.Sign}"/>
   <StackPanel>
       <local:IndicatorLigth ActiveColor="Thistle" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.Sign}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The Sign parameter belongs to an IsEnabled bindable property of a ComboBox which not in the XAML code. The label content is correct, it changes when I change combobox enabled status, but my UserControl setter of Value, OnSetColorChanged and callmyInstanceMethod don't fire. Could you tell me what wrong in my code? Thank you very much.

Update: So I was wrong. The code mentioned above is correct. The problem will be occures when I push the stackpanel into a devexpress LayoutGroup HeaderTemplate:

```
<dxlc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top"> 
<dxlc:LayoutGroup.HeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.Sign}"/>
      <StackPanel>
         <local:IndicatorLigth ActiveColor="Thistle" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.Sign}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</dxlc:LayoutGroup.HeaderTemplate>
</dxlc:LayoutGroup>
```

Comment: If you enable WPF tracing (e.g. Tools/Options/Debugging/Output Window/WPF Trace Settings/DataBinding = Warning), do you see something in the debug output window?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. DataBinding option is in warning status, but there are no binding errors in output window :-|

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but you should get rid of `DataContext = this;` in the usercontrol constructor. That's very bad practice: It will break any default-source binding on any instance of the usercontrol. The reason people do that is so they can avoid using RelativeSource bindings inside the UserControl's own XAML, but you're already correctly using RelativeSource in the UserControl XAML. Again, I doubt that this is the solution to the problem you have here -- but it may be the solution to your next problem.

Comment: The solution to your present problem depends on context: In the version that doesn't work, is there an ancestor which is a UserControl, whose DataContext has a property named Sign, and is it the same instance of that DataContext object that you think it is? By the way, the setter for `Value` (`set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }`) will never be called when Value is set via a binding/attribute. Those will just go straight to calling `SetValue()`.

Comment: @74hakansukur: Are you seeing the expected value in the `Label` but the `Value` property isn't set? What's the type of `Sign`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disturbing you and thank you for advices. I have found the cause of problem. I needn't use `<HeaderTemplate><DataTemplate>`, I  have to use simple `<Header>` block :)